# Call Observable on runtime and render the result

Tags: angular, observable, angular-router, angular-httpclient

I have a View, where when clicked a button like this

```
  <a class="button" (click)="takeInpit(id)" routerLinkActive="activebutton"  >Request</a>
```

triggers this takeInput method

```
public takeInpit(Id:string): void{

    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        "id":Id
      }
  };
  this.router.navigate(["request"], navigationExtras);
  }
```

Then I navigate to this component called request:

```
//takes parameters from container
  public constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private itemService: SingleItemService) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.requestedItem = params["id"];
        this.itemService.setIDs(this.requestedItem);
        this.itemService.getSingleItemRequest();
    });
    this.item = this.itemService.getName();
    //console.log(this.item);
    
}
```

where I'm calling this service with the idea that I can take dynamically data from an API

```
export class SingleItemService {

  urlSingle:string = 'http://localhost:8080/getSpecificItem?itemId=';
  item:any;
  
  constructor(private htpp: HttpClient){
  }

  public setIDs(id:string){
    this.urlSingle + id;
}

  public getSingleItemRequest():void{
     this.htpp.get<Item>(this.urlSingle).subscribe( data=>{
     this.item = data;
     console.log("data is", data);
     }
   );
   }

   public getName(): string{
      return this.item.name;
    
   }
}
```

and after that log the data at the request component View (the one that called the service basically)

```
<div ngIf* ="item"><div>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

However the info is not logged. Checking the console i see this message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.item is undefined
getName@http://localhost:4200/main.js:368:9
```

so It tries to access the service's get method BEFORE the observable is done. How can I fix that?

Comment: using the api response is an asynchronous way of accessing the data. To do so in an HTML you can use async pipes, more info can be found at https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SingleItemService` return Observable from `getSingleItemRequest`, use [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) to assign response to item.

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

public getSingleItemRequest():Observable<any>{
     return this.htpp.get<Item>(this.urlSingle).pipe(
        tap(data => this.item = data)
    );
}
```

In `RequestComponent`

```
item = '';

this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.requestedItem = params["id"];
    this.itemService.setIDs(this.requestedItem);
    this.itemService.getSingleItemRequest()
    .subscribe(_ => this.item = this.itemService.getName());
    // .subscribe(response => this.item = response.name);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my issue! I am new to Angular will read about pipes!